# Wordpress wp_dropdown_pages is not attached via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to add Wordpress `wp_dropdown_pages()` to my table as `tbody` row via `jQuery`. But i get following script error in my firebug

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ->  label for = "" > Select Page < /label><select name='upr_page[]' id='upr_page[]'
```

My `jQuery` code is

```
$('#user-manage-table tr:last').after('<tr>< td class = "user-page-class" >< div class = "form-group" >< label for = "" > Select Page < /label><?php wp_dropdown_pages(array("name" => "upr_page[]")); ?>< /div>< /td>< /tr>');
```

And in view page source window i see following code in `jQuery`

```
$('#user-manage-table tr:last').after('<tr><td><div class="form-group"><label>Select User</label><select class="form-control" name="upr_users[]"><option value=2>abc< /option><option value=1>admin< /option><option value=3>def< /option>< /select>< /div>< /td>< td class = "user-page-class" >< div class = "form-group" >< label for = "" > Select Page < /label><select name='upr_page[]' id='upr_page[]'>
<option class="level-0" value="50">Cart</option>
<option class="level-0" value="51">Checkout</option>
<option class="level-0" value="88">Dashboard</option>
<option class="level-0" value="84">Job List</option>
<option class="level-0" value="52">My Account</option>
<option class="level-0" value="82">Post Job</option>
<option class="level-0" value="2">Sample Page</option>
<option class="level-0" value="49">Shop</option>
<option class="level-0" value="90">Transactions</option></select></div></td></tr>');
```

How can i solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Full JS code

```
$('#create-new-user-role').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#user-manage-table tr:last').after('<tr><td class = 'user-page-class'>< div class = 'form-group' ><label for = '' > Select Page </label><?php wp_dropdown_pages(array('name' => 'upr_page[]')); ?>< /div>< /td>< /tr>');
            });
```

Comment: Can you show more of your js code?

Comment: Have you seen that you have single quotes in the single quotes? See how SO highlighted it for you. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: I have solved it another way. I retrieved all pages id and name using Wordpress functions and added in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change single quotes to double in the end of the first line of the last code snippet.

This is not a valid string, so, jQuery expect the closing `)`. You can have one single quotes (the one around the whole string), and use double quotes all around the string (or vice versa) or you should escape the single quotes in the string.

Comment: My last code snippet is from my firefox view source window. My code is `$('#user-manage-table tr:last').after('<tr><td class = "user-page-class" >< div class = "form-group" ><label for = "" > Select Page </label><?php wp_dropdown_pages(array("name" => "upr_page[]")); ?>< /div>< /td>< /tr>');`

Comment: @andDev oh, you are right, this is not the answer, sorry.